# Looking at Time Vs Index

Tags: time-series, data-visualization, signal-processing

I have a collection of times, and I'm trying to analyze relative distances between different times.

When visualizing this data, does it make sense to plot (idx,time), where idx in the index of a set of data.

i.e you have an array of a bunch of times that an event occurred (say when a signal was detected). You then sort those times and plot them against their respective index in the array.

Does the resulting graph have any analytical value?

Comment: Possibly. This seems a little abstract to me, & removed from my typical scenario. Can you say more about your actual situation, & post the plot in question?

Comment: @gung I'll get a plot, but the scenario is something like recording the times someone hits a button. Each time they hit that button a timestamp is recorded, and you want to evaluate the times between button presses and some other stuff. You could (1) treat every ms with a button press as being `on` (i.e. 1) and all else as `off` (i.e. 0). I was wondering if there was any value in just plotting the times against their index through.

Comment: That sounds like you might be referring to a [Poisson process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking at Pandas Python library for processing time-series data. Measurements can be stored in a Pandas data frame and associated to a time stamp using the Series object.

The Pandas Series object allows easy processing of time series such as merging, decimation, sorting and basic statistics.